# List of dictionary as tables

Tags: python, html

I want to display the content of json format to a table in the browser.

```
import json
import requests
import tabulate
import ast

url = "http://localhost:8080/api/vi/empdata"
headers = {
     'cache-control': "no-cache",
     'postman-token': "72c97887-727e-ae9e-36ed-182f725fb6b5"
   }
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
ult_list = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(data))
header = ult_list[0].keys()
rows =  [x.values() for x in ult_list]
print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, header))
```

The Output is as follows:

```
name                 address 
-------------------- --------- 
Aarush               Yoyager 
Sanju                Victor 
Zara                 Voyager 
Sangeetha Narayanlal Voyager
```

But i want the output something like a table:

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Can you give a sample output... your current output is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

See, this isn't that difficult to do if you create a dictionary of values.

What I mean to say is, inside your list comprehension, just create a dictionary for each combination as put all the names under a key called 'name' and the addresses as values of a key named address.

Then just do this:

```
pd.DataFrame([name,address])
```

This should work.